# Finding specific pixel values ​​in ArcGIS using Python

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, raster, arcpy

I have a raster file containing some integer values.

I need to find all pixels whose values are not defined in list like this one:

`l = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128]`.

Is there any easy way to solve that problem without converting raster to points and editing attribute table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Extract by attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000029000000) using 
`"VALUE NOT IN (1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128)"` (Thanks to @afalciano)
will give you a new raster with only the cells where the value is different from your list.

Comment: ...or using `"VALUE NOT IN (1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128)"`

Comment: That would be more convenient of course.. Thanks, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use a SQL statement within a [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) function.  The following example performs the following actions:

1. Generate a SQL expression from a list of values.  Doing this in an
   automated fashion is important for long lists of values.
2. Use Con to perform an if/else evaluation on a raster.  In this case,
   all values in the list will be assigned "1" and all others "0".

---

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension = "Spatial"

vals = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128]
inRaster = r'C:\temp\example.tif'
new = []

# Generate a SQL expression from the "vals" list
for i in vals:
    new.append("value " + "= " + str(i) + " OR ")
    expression = ''.join(new)[:-4]

# Use Con to convert all raster values from the "vals" list to 1 and all others to 0
outCon = Con(inRaster, 1, 0, expression)
outCon.save("C:/temp/revisedRaster.tif")
```